# Bubble sort not printing last element

Tags: sorting

My code asks a user to enter an amount of temperatures and prints out the average, then sorts the temperatures in ascending order and descending order. For ascending order I've used selection sort and for descending order I've used bubble sort. My problem is that when I use bubble sort, the last sorted element does not print and I'm not sure why it's doing this. What am I doing wrong?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many temperatures?");
    int size=keyboard.nextInt();
    int temp[]=new int[size];
    System.out.println("Please enter "+temp.length+" temperatures");
    double sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
        temp[i]=keyboard.nextInt();
        sum=sum+temp[i];
    }
    double average=sum/temp.length;
    System.out.println("The average temperature is: "+average);


  System.out.println(" "); 
  System.out.println("Selection sort algorithm for ascending order");
  int min;
  for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {

    min = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < temp.length; j++) {
        if (temp[j] < temp[min]) {
            min = j;
        }
    }
    if (min != i) {
        int temporary_var = temp[i];
        temp[i] = temp[min];
        temp[min] = temporary_var;
    }
    System.out.print(temp[i]+ " ");

}
 System.out.println("");
 System.out.println("Bubble sort algorithm for descending order");   
 for(int i=0; i<temp.length-1; i++)
 {
  if(temp[i]>temp[i+1])  
  {
   int temporary_var = temp[i ];                //swap elements
   temp[i] = temp[ i+1 ];
   temp[i+1] =  temporary_var; 
  }
 System.out.print(temp[i]+" ");    
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing in the sorting loop which is `for(int i=0; i<temp.length-1; i++)` having length-1. That is why it does not print the last element. Change it to `for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++)` since you already have a `<` than operator.

Comment: When I use for(int i=0; i<temp.length; i++) I get an error

Comment: instead of if(temp[i]>temp[i+1])  use if((i<temp.length -1) && temp[i]>temp[i+1])

Comment: I'll try this because I had an index out of bounds exception

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Your bubble sort algorithm is correct. Just one loop and swapping? it's just one pass of bubble sort and that won't sort the array for you. 
First correct your algorithm and then output the numbers outside loop 
Here's the correct code for bubble sort

```
    for(int k=0; k<temp.length; k++)
     {
      for(int i=0;i<temp.length-1;i++)
      {
        if(temp[i]>temp[i+1])  
        {
          int temporary_var = temp[i ];                //swap elements
          temp[i] = temp[ i+1 ];
          temp[i+1] =  temporary_var; 
        }  

    }

//print array here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bubble sort's print statement is part of a for loop that only reaches an index of length minus 2. On zero indexed arrays the last index is length - 1.